# Laravel elixir webpack Error (must have normal or pitch function)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I can't get this to work searched the whole internet but nothing found. I develop a app with Laravel using elixir. The Problem is if I use gulp in my terminal then I get this error "throw new Error("Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)");" and I dont know what to do. May somebody please help me out?

gulpfile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(mix => {
 mix.sass('app.scss')
   .sass('bootstrap.scss')
   .sass('flexslider.scss')
   .sass('admin.scss')
   .webpack('app.js')
   .webpack('bootstrap.js')
   .webpack('jquery.flexslider-min.js')
   .webpack('masonry.pkgd.js')
   .webpack('imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js');

mix.version(["css/app.css","css/bootstrap.css", "css/flexslider.css", 
"css/admin.css", "js/bootstrap.js", "js/app.js", "js/jquery.flexslider-
min.js", "js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js", "js/masonry.pkgd.js"]);
});
```

Best regards

Comment: what are you using exactly gulp or webpack? can you show the configration ?

Comment: where can i find the config? Iam using gulp with a gulpfile. The strange thing is everything worked a time ago.

Comment: but question titles include webpack error ?